# Objective C: Why is Button moving?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button

I've got a rather strange bug in my app. Whenever I press the second Button that makes the Method go into the "if", one of my Buttons moves a bit to the left.

It looks like this: http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/3686/30000000.jpg

My App:
I've got 12 buttons in a row with Letters on them. Every button has a label above it.
The labels are called Label0, Label1, Label 2,...
There is a word in the String myString. If the button pressed has the first letter of the word on it -> write it in the first label -> look at second letter of the word...

```
/// Global ///
start = 4;
letterCount = start; 
currentChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[myString characterAtIndex:0]];


- (IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender { 

UILabel *label = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label%i" , letterCount]];

if ([[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:currentChar]) {
    label.text = currentChar;
    label.hidden = NO;

    if (letterCount-start < [myString length]-1) {
        letterCount++;
    }


    currentChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[myString characterAtIndex:letterCount-start]];
}
```

Nothing in that code seams to fool around with the position of the buttons. Nevertheless its moving... every time...

I'm using xCode 4.6.1

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 2):

Try removing that button and adding a new one (giving the new button the same name as the old one) and re-attach all of your IB stuff and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Can't believe that was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Not unusual though. When ever strange things happen when IB is involved, delete all the view items within IB and re-create them. Set Names, lables, references etc as they used to be and sometimes a myracle happens ...